# R: ggtern does not work, broken with new ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtern

I'm trying to use the [ggtern](http://www.ggtern.com/) package to plot some plots. It used to run on ggplot2, but now it doesn't work and breaks ggplot2.

When I run the following:

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(1,2)
library(ggtern)
qplot(3,4)

df = data.frame(x = runif(50),
                y = runif(50),
                z = runif(50),
                Value = runif(50,1,10),
                Group = as.factor(round(runif(50,1,2))))
ggtern(data=df,aes(x,y,z,color=Group)) +
  theme_rgbw() +
  geom_point() + geom_path() +
  labs(x="X",y="Y",z="Z",title="Title")
```

`qplot(1,2)` works just fine, `library(ggtern)` gives me this (which may or may not be related to the problem):

```
Attaching package: ‘ggtern’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:ggplot2’:

    %+%, %+replace%, aes, calc_element, Geom, geom_segment, ggplot_build,
    ggplot_gtable, ggsave, theme, theme_bw, theme_classic, theme_get, theme_gray,
    theme_grey, theme_minimal, theme_set, theme_update
```

`qplot(3,4)` fails with this:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : attempt to apply non-function
```

And if I comment it out and it reaches the `ggtern(...` I get this:

```
Error in coord_tern() : could not find function "coord"
```

Obviously, something is wrong. Where do I start looking for what's wrong? What's this function `coord` and why is it gone?

Comment: ggplot2 has had a major update recently. Depending packages need to be adapted for ggplot2's internal changes. It seems like ggtern masks a lot of fundamental ggplot2 functions.

Comment: `gtern` is now broken with the new package (from a remark I read by Hadley). The maintainer is apparently not around to make the necessary changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, `ggtern 2.0.1` is now available, published on CRAN a couple of days ago after completely re-writing the package to be compatible with`ggplot2 2.0.0`. A summary of the new functionality in `ggtern 2.0.X` can be found [here](http://ahref.io/UuED1):

Here is what your code produces under the new package:

[image: solution]

Comment: Problem is back as of March 9, 2016. Plots fail with same error as in original post as can be seen in CRAN package check results ftp://r-project.org/pub/R/web/checks/check_results_ggtern.html

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem with ggtern faulting.  My work around was downloading and installing the 1.0.1 version of ggplot2.  Archived versions can be found at "cran.r-project.org" website at https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive

Answer (score 0):

Quoting an email from the developer:

> I have just released the new ggtern 2.0.1 version, compatible with
>   ggplot2 2.0.

Should be ok now.